# Using a conditional environment{ } directive in Jenkinsfiles

Tags: jenkins, git, jenkinsfile

My Jenkinsfiles use the environment{} directive. I've been trying to set a condition where I invoke different variables depending on the GIT branch being builded.

I've tried something like e. g. :

```
switch(branch_name) {
   case 'dev' :
    Var1 = x;
   case 'master' :
    Var1 = y;
}
```

That would allow me skip using different Jenkinsfiles for each branch on a repo. But groovy syntax seems not to work inside this environment{} directive.

Is there a way tackling it? Or would you suggest another approach for handling different global variables for each branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I often have an extra `Prepare` stage to calculate these logics:

```java
stage('Prepare') {
   steps {
      script {
         switch(branch_name) {
            case 'dev' :
               env.VAR_1 = x;
            case 'master' :
               env.VAR_1 = y;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

`env.` will set the global environment for you.

Comment: the ".env" did the trick. Much appreciated.